# Overwriting HDFS file/directory through Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs, overwrite

**Problem**

I have a file saved in HDFS and all I want to do is to run my spark application, calculate a result `javaRDD` and use `saveAsTextFile()` in order to store the new "file" in HDFS.

However Spark's `saveAsTextFile()` does not work if the file already exists. It does not overwrite it.

**What I tried**

So I searched for a solution to this and I found that a possible way to make it work could be deleting the file through the HDFS API before trying to save the new one.

I added the Code:

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
Path newFolderPath = new Path("hdfs://node1:50050/hdfs/" +filename);

if(hdfs.exists(newFolderPath)){
    System.out.println("EXISTS");
    hdfs.delete(newFolderPath, true);
}

filerdd.saveAsTextFile("/hdfs/" + filename);
```

When I tried to run my Spark application, the file was deleted but I get a `FileNotFoundException`.

Considering the fact, that this exception occurs when someone is trying to read a file from a path and the file does not exist, this makes no sense because after deleting the file, there is no code that tries to read it.

**Part of my code**

```
 JavaRDD<String> filerdd = sc.textFile("/hdfs/" + filename)    // load the file here
 ...
 ...
 // Transformations here
 filerdd = filerdd.map(....);
 ...
 ...

 // Delete old file here
 FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
 Path newFolderPath = new Path("hdfs://node1:50050/hdfs/" +filename);

 if(hdfs.exists(newFolderPath)){
    System.out.println("EXISTS");
    hdfs.delete(newFolderPath, true);
 }

 // Write new file here
 filerdd.saveAsTextFile("/hdfs/" + filename);
```

I am trying to do the simplest thing here but I have no idea why this does not work. Maybe the filerdd is somehow connected to the path??

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use the same path for input and output. Spark's RDD will be executed lazily. It runs when you call `saveAsTextFile`. At this point, you have already deleted the `newFolderPath`. So `filerdd` will complain.

Anyway, you should not use the same path for input and output.

Comment: But saving the file in another path in HDFS won't work for me because I execute my spark application several times and I always want to use the latest file saved as input.

Comment: Just save the file in a temp path. After running `saveAsTextFile`, you can remove the input and rename the temp path using the input path.